# Generating java from wsdl failure

Tags: web-services, tomcat, wsdl, apache-axis

I am trying to generate service stub from a wsdl file but I keep getting the error message on windows command prompt when I type the following:

```
C:\path to dir containing the wsdl file> wsdl2java -uri ./[WSDL FILE NAME]
```

I have set up the following environment variables:

```
AXIS2_HOME - C:\axis2\bin
PATH       - C:\axis2\bin\wsdl2java.bat
```

The wsdl2java.bat file is in the bin dir of axis2. But I can't figure out why I get this error. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATH - C:\axis2\bin\wsdl2java.bat is invalid. Try to set PATH - C:\axis2\bin\ and then restart cmd / powershell

Comment: 'wsdl2java' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: PATH - C:\axis2\bin\wsdl2java.bat is invalid. Try to set PATH - C:\axis2\bin\ and then restart cmd / powershell.

Comment: Thank you. That was the main problem. I also had to change the variable of AXIS2_HOME to C:\axis2

Comment: @SasoMadaric right now your answer doesn't contain any solution to the problem. Please [[edit]] it and include advice from comment. In this form your answer has high chances to be deleted as "not an answer".